# Converting NSSecureCoding to NSData - Xcode - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, nsdata

I have some code that creates an NSSecureCoding variable called "content" and I want to convert that variable into NSData that can then be made into a UIImage or be sent to a local server. How do I convert this properly? I want this for a Share Extension I am making in my iOS app, so when you press share on a photo, it gets the photo contents and converts it into NSData. Here is my code:

```
    inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as NSExtensionItem
    attachment = inputItem.attachments![0] as NSItemProvider
    if (attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String)){
        attachment.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String,
            options: nil,
            completionHandler: {(content, error: NSError!) in

                //insert code to convert "content"(NSSecureCoding) to NSData variable

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {

    attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var image: UIImage?

        if item is UIImage {
            image = item as? UIImage
        }

        if item is URL {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: item as! URL)
            image = UIImage(data: data!)!
        }

        if item is Data {
            image = UIImage(data: item as! Data)!
        }

        if let image = image {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // image here
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

kinda late but this happened to me today and I solved it like this,
inside the `completionHandler`:

```
  if let data = content {
        self.imageData = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: data as! NSURL)!)                      
  }
```

imageData is UIImage type.